# Please help me to solve this code ($default='blue')

Tags: php, moodle

I am use this code for making a function for color changes 
my moodle lib.php the code is

```
    function learningbell_initialise_colourswitcher(moodle_page $page) {
    user_preference_allow_ajax_update('theme_learningbell_chosen_colour', PARAM_ALPHA);
    $page->requires->yui_module('moodle-theme_learningbell-colourswitcher', 'M.theme_learningbell.initColourSwitcher', array(array('div'=>'#colourswitcher')));
}

/**
 * Gets the colour the user has selected, or the default if they have never changed
 *
 * @param string $default The default colour to use, normally red
 * @return string The colour the user has selected
 */
function learningbell_get_colour($default='blue') {
    return get_user_preferences('theme_learningbell_chosen_colour', $default);
}

/**
 * Checks if the user is switching colours with a refresh (JS disabled)
 *
 * If they are this updates the users preference in the database
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function learningbell_check_colourswitch() {
    $changecolour = optional_param('learningbellcolour', null, PARAM_ALPHA);
    if (in_array($changecolour, array('blue', 'green', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'pink'))) {
        return set_user_preference('theme_learningbell_chosen_colour', $changecolour);
    }
    return false;
}
```

but i want to make default color should be selected color like any color ('blue', 'green', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'pink') which one currently selected by admin. If i am select pink color, but the problem is that after logout it takes automatic blue color
please help me.

Comment: Give it as param to the function?

Comment: If its not clear, make it clear. How can we know which color you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the user preference before calling get_user_preference()?

```
$selectedcolour = ...
set_user_preference('theme_learningbell_chosen_colour', $selectedcolour);
```